# Geolocation to find nearest city

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, apache

I have a database of city names (Chicago, New York, Nashville, etc.).  Only a few of them have coordinates.  What's the simplest way for me to programmatically match the closest city/area in my database to their current location whether on a mobile device or on a desktop?

I'm on a shared server so I can't install any apache modules.

**Update**

Lets say coordinates weren't a problem.  If coordinates in my database weren't an issue, what would be the best way to do this?  Use HTML 5 to get the current user's coordinates and just run a simple query to determine the closest location?

Answer (score 2):

Use a service like [GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) you can download a free database or use their API.

*** Edit ***

Here is their city specific page - http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

Comment: That's fantastic, but it requires an apache mod which I don't have permissions to install on my shared server.

Comment: Not sure what you really need, but you can use GeoIP by just copying the files "GeoIP.dat" and "geoip.inc" into a directory. No need to install anything, i'm using it this way and it works great.

Comment: Really?  Fantastic, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

I would say get a better database. Look online for a US census zipcode database. It has coordinates for every zipcode across the US. From there, geolocate the user, and find the closest zipcode, city, or whatever using the circle distance formula.

OR

get fancypants. Geohash the entire zipcode database (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). then geohash the user's coordinates. compare geohashes to find the closest zipcode, city, whatever. The best thing about geohash is it doesnt require any crazy circle distance formula.

This may not be the latest and greatest, but you get the point: http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/zips.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can have a US Zipcode database using which you can get desire output.

Download Zipcode database from IPinfo DB. refer below URL
http://ipinfodb.com/zipcode_database.php

Now USE Below MYSQL function to findout Distance from currunt geolocation (latitude and longitude).

```
DELIMITER $$    
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `great_circle_distance`$$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `great_circle_distance`(
    lat1 DOUBLE(10,6),
    lon1 DOUBLE(10,6),
    lat2 DOUBLE(10,6),
    lon2 DOUBLE(10,6)
    ) RETURNS double(10,2)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
                    DECLARE delta_lat DOUBLE(10,6);
                    DECLARE delta_lon DOUBLE(10,6);
                    DECLARE temp1 DOUBLE(10,6);
                    DECLARE EARTH_RADIUS DOUBLE(10,2);
                    DECLARE distance DOUBLE(10,2);
                    SET lat1 = RADIANS(lat1);
                    SET lon1 = RADIANS(lon1);
                    SET lat2 = RADIANS(lat2);
                    SET lon2 = RADIANS(lon2);
                    SET delta_lat = lat2 - lat1;
                    SET delta_lon = lon2 - lon1;

                    SET temp1 = pow(sin(delta_lat/2.0),2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(sin(delta_lon/2.0),2);
                    SET EARTH_RADIUS = 3956.0;
                    SET distance = EARTH_RADIUS * 2 * atan2(sqrt(temp1),sqrt(1-temp1));
                    RETURN distance;
        END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Below Query will help you to get result or you can modify query as per your need.

```
Select TA.city, great_circle_distance(TA.lat,TA.log, 32.2342,-72.42342) AS Distance FROM zipcodes AS TA Order BY Distance Limit 1;
```